# AEM 6.3 - Requested Path *.servlet is not in available search paths / 500 Server Error

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

We had some services work properly but after a server restart we are seeing a bank response  / 500 Server Error .

Not sure what is wrong? Appreciate any help!

Error message in logs are like: Requested Path /bin/xx/report.servlet is not in available search paths for any custom service we developed.

Snippet form logs:
`21.09.2018 10:52:30.448 *WARN* [192.150.10.209 [1537541550444] POST /bin/sirius/report HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.components.ComponentCacheImpl Requested Path /bin/xx/report.servlet is not in available search paths`

Sling Servlet Resolver shows the correct class:

[image]

Bundle is also Active:

[image]

Comment: Potential helps: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2464577 and https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2482292

Comment: Do you think it is referrer filter? Try to allow empty or remove POST method under filter. Refer this: https://taylor.callsen.me/security-and-java-servlets-in-aem-6-1/

Comment: We restarted AEM and the services started to work. Still trying to find the root cause.

Comment: Is that normal to have several bundles just in the installed state? Maybe a dependency was not running.